# CodeIgniter - Ajax validation not working correct and not storing data in database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, validation, jquery

I'd like some help please.

1. From my tests till now, I get these:

   - If validation fails - The div #ajaxResults from my view gets the class alert-error and shows the errors (as expected).
   - If validation succeeds - The div #ajaxResults gets the class alert-error (not expected) and shows true (as expected).

What I'd like to do is when there's an ajax request is this:

- If the validation succeeds - return the div #ajaxResults with a class alert-success(bootstrap) and also display a message saying "data stored in database successfully". I can't figure out how should I return and the message from the controller.
- If the validation fails to show the div #ajaxResults with a class alert-error with the validation errors. (as it is)

2.Also I have notice that in case of a NON-ajax-request the data are stored in the database, but in case of an ajax-request don't. How can I fix this to work correct??

This is my controller

```
public function manage($id = NULL){
    $this->layout->add_includes('js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')->add_includes('js/ajax_scripts.js');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

$data['categ'] = $this->category_model->with_parents();

//fetch a single product or create a new one
if ( isset($id) ) {
    $data['prod'] = $this->product_model->get($id);
    $data['attr'] = $this->attributes_model->get_by('product_id', $id);
} else {
    $data['prod'] = $this->product_model->make_new();
    $data['attr'] = $this->attribute_model->make_new();
} 
if ( isset($_POST['general_settings']) ) {
    if ($this->form_validation->run('product_rules') === true) {
        // get post inputs and store them in database
        $data = $this->product_model->input_posts(array('product_name', 'brand', 'category_id', 'general_description','visible'));
        $this->product_model->save($data, $id);

        $result = array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'data stored in database successfully');
    } else {
        // validation failed
        $result = array('status' => 400, 'reason' => validation_errors());
    }
    if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $result);
    redirect('admin/product');
}

// if ( isset($_POST['attribute_settings']) ) { same goes here }



// load the view
$this->load->view('admin/products/manage', $data);
}
```

this is my js script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form.ajax-form').on('submit', function() {
        var obj = $(this), // (*) references the current object/form each time
            url = obj.attr('action'),
            method = obj.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        obj.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var obj = $(this),
                name = obj.attr('name'),
                value = obj.val();

            data[name] = value;
        });
        // console.log(data);

        // data.general_settings = 1;
        $.ajax({ // see the (*)
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                //console.log(response);
                $('#ajaxResults').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-error');
$('.control-group').removeClass('error warning error info success');
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-success').html(response.message);
$('.control-group').addClass('success'); // ** apply it only on valid fields
                } else {
                    $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(response.reason);
$('.control-group').addClass('error'); // ** apply it only on invalid fields
                }
            }
        });
        return false; //disable refresh
    });
});
```

one of my forms with class .ajax-form inside the view

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/product/manage/'.$prod->product_id, array('class' => 'ajax-form')); ?>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="product_name">Product *</label>
    <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?php echo set_value('product_name', $prod->product_name); ?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('product_name'); ?>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="brand">Brand</label>
    <input type="text" name="brand" value="<?php echo set_value('brand', $prod->brand); ?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('brand'); ?>
</div>
// apply same to all my fields
    <p>
         <label for="category_id">Category *</label>
         <?php echo form_dropdown('category_id', $categ);
               echo form_error('category_id');
            ?>
    </p>
    <p>
          <label for="general_description">General Description</label>
          <textarea class="ckeditor" name="general_description" rows="10" cols="250"><?php echo set_value('general_description', $prod->general_description); ?></textarea>
           <?php echo form_error('general_description') . PHP_EOL; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
          <label for="visible">Visible</label>
          <select name="visible" class="span1">
              <option value="0">No</option>
             <option value="1">Yes</option>
          </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="general_settings">Ok</button>
    </p>
<?php echo form_close() . PHP_EOL; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As I'm understand You need something like this (I've put just code fragments).

Controller:

```
if($this->form_validation->run('product_rules') === true){
    //your code will be here
    $result = array(
        'status' => 200, 'message' => 'data stored in database successfully'
    );
}
else{
    $result = array('status' => 400, 'reason' => validation_errors());
}
if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $result);
    redirect('admin/product');
}
```

Ajax function:

```
data.general_settings = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        $('#ajaxResults').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-error');
        if(response.status == 200){
            $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-success').html(response.message);
        }
        else{
            $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(response.reason);
        }
    }
});
```

- Are You saw same errors in firebug for ajax request?

Comment: I did your changes and seems to work but there are still some issues.
If the first time the validation failes it returns the errors in the alert-error, as expected, but if i submit the form again correctly it shows the success message inside the alert-error again.

And secondly in the Ajax-request scenario the data are not stored in the database, whereas in a non-ajax the do. Ican't figure out whats wrong

Comment: 1. Please, see success() function, I've updated it. 2. Are You see any errors in firebug?

Comment: @2. no errors. If the validation succeeds it shows the success message else the validation errors

Comment: Try to dump `message` from `session->flashdata` in `admin/product`. Any errors are exists?

Comment: this will be in a non-ajax request, right? How can i do this?

Comment: How are you test non-ajax requests?

Comment: if i disable the javascript from Firefox, and submit the form the data are stored in database. Check from phpmyadmin. If I enable the javascript the data not stored, I have the values from the last time.

Comment: Try to set breakpoints into `manage()` method for ajax requests. Maybe some data are not sending to server

Comment: I'm sory but I don't understand what you mean. Could you please explain more thoroughly, or give me an example???

Comment: Where You set `general_settings` variable into your `data` object in js?

Comment: Into your `manage()` method are located this code `if (isset($_POST['general_settings']))`. But I'm don't see where you pass `general_settings` variable into `data` object in ajax function. Please, see updated code.

Comment: the general_settings is the name of the submit button. I have 2 forms inside my view with the class .ajax-form, so if the button general_settings is pressed it runs the validation for general settings (product). please review my code I did an update.

Comment: the button i guess is passed throught the type="submit". In js is here on('submit', function()..

Comment: try to add `general_settings`. Please, see my updated ajax code and try it

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. To give you some more feedback I have 2 forms in my view with class .ajax-form. If you see in manage() if also have 'if (isset($_POST['attributes_settings']))'. This is the second button of second form. Both forms do the same thing. They use the same flexible script in irder to store data in database, but each time i proccess one form only, so the first time if i press general_settings button the product's data should be stored and if i press the attributes_settings button, then the attributes should be stored

Comment: I've tried to emulate your code as possible and all works are fine with ajax and non-ajax requests.

Comment: That's weird... Does anything have to do with my submit buttons, or the fact that i have 2 forms?? I don't get it.. I did console.log in many points of my script and it shows all post data..

Comment: I think I found out what's my problem. The problem is ckeditor in textarea(!!). I removed it and tried to enter data and it works! I can do both Inserts and Updates! .. Any ideas why is causing this and how I can fix it????

Comment: How can I apply the bootstrap validation fields?? currently when I hit submit all my fields are styled red even those which are valid. I want to be styled red only the invalid ones (and those who are valid to style in green). please review my view and my js to see